# Are Hindi "Bigul" (बिगुल) and English "Bugle" cognates?

Tags: english, comparative-linguistics, cognates, hindustani

In Hindi, Bigul (बिगुल) (IPA /bigul/) is a bugle-like instrument, if they are cognates can someone also tell me how they might have been formed.!

Comment: The English comes from Late Latin *buculus* "little bull"; the Hindi might be a loan from English at some point. I need to find a reliable etymological dictionary of Hindi to check though.

Comment: Can you give it in Hindi or Urdu script?

Comment: Draconis yeah it just might be possible, by voicing /k/ there . But, is the first u a schwa?

Comment: @WiccanKarnak It is not; it's in fact a long vowel: *būculus*. I seem to have mistyped before. And the first syllable has the stress.

Comment: @Draconis then i think it would be difficult to convert a long u to /i/ sound right?

Comment: @WiccanKarnak I would agree, but strange things can happen to vowels.

Comment: @WiccanKarnak: In French, Latin ū became [y], which is like [i] but rounded. Loanwords from French into other languages may use /i/ as an approximation of French /y/. But I don't know if it's plausible that the word is a loanword from French. And in any case, the /u/ in the second syllable would be surprising to me in that case--I'd expect French *bugle* /bygl(ə)/ to be adopted in Hindi as something like "bigla", not "bigul"

Comment: @sumelic. European loan words in Hindi are from English (mainly) or from Portuguese (some early borrowings), not from French.

Comment: @sumelic thanks a lot for that, was looking for that perfectly as an analysis to what Draconis said.

Comment: @draconis _strange things_ XD

Comment: Not all questions have a site to be asked on. This kind of question is best answered by checking etymological dictionaries.

Comment: @curiousdannii ik, but I did ask the question only after _not_ finding it in an etymological dictionary. Also if you follow the comments, it's more like drawing a _linguistic_ connection or explaining why it happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shyamsundara Dasa's *Hindi Shabdasagar* dictionary has an entry [(link)](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.12:1:4500.dasahindi.2497790):

> **बिगुल** संज्ञा पुं० [अं०] अँगरेजी ढंग की एक प्रकार की तुरही जो प्रायः सैनिकों को एकत्र करने अथवा इसी प्रकार का कोई और काम करने के लिये संकेत रूप में बजाई जाती है । मुहा०—**बिगुल बजना** = (१) किसी कार्य के लिये आदेश होना । (२) कूच होना ।

It says "an English style of horn usually used to call soldiers to one place, or in other cases [used] as a signal". The [अं०] part means it's a borrowing from English, so fdb is correct. *Rajpal Hindi Dictionary* also agrees.

Answer (score 4):

"Bigul" is not in Turner's Comparative Dictionary, nor in Platts' Dictionary of Classical Urdu/Hindi. It is evidently a borrowing from English, with simplification of the /ju/ in the first syllable to /i/.

Comment: Thanks fdb, though (being an Indian myself) I know, and I found in texts the mention of ancient buffalo horn made wind instrument being called bigul. Plus it was more of a tribal thing way back, I doubt that it would have made it's way to the Dictionaries anyways (if the word did exist)

Comment: I found in texts the mention of ancient buffalo horn made wind instrument being called _bigul_ . Plus it was more of a tribal thing way back, I doubt that it would have made it's way to the Dictionaries anyways (if the word did exist) and that it was a borrowing.

Comment: @WiccanKarnak. Are you talking about old texts (pre-1800)? If so, could you give some references?

Comment: I don't have _proofs_ as they are generally conveyed as folklore by oral methods. (So in the days of kings, if there was an announcement, it would be preceded by _bigul_ sounds) But, I could Google and find an 1857 _reference_ (again not a proof), of _bigul_ being played before the Indian mutiny.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer I accepted @Aryaman 's answer because it had a reference. Plus have upvote both